# Get substring between first and nth occurence of pattern

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, substring

I am attempting to extract a substring between the first and nth occurence of a pattern in a linux shell (using sed, awk, ...).

Example string:

```
AAA_BBBB__CCC__GGGG___fffffffffffffff_hhhh
```

I need the substrig after the first occurence of `"*_"` (n concatenated underscores) until the nth occurence of `"*_"`.

E.g., the result for substring between 1st and 4th occurence would be

```
BBBB__CCC__GGGG
```

Using sed, or awk or other tools what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: In your desired output, why is there 1 underscore before CCC but 2 after?

Comment: When you say "n concatenated underscores" do you mean "1 or more underscores"? If so that'd be `__*` as a BRE or `_+` as an ERE, not `*_`.

Comment: Sorry glenn jackmann, that was a typo.
It is indeed 1 or more underscore. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `sed`. This will select the substring between the 1st and nth occurrence. The number present is in the form `n - 1`:

```
sed 's/^[^_]\+_\+\(\(_*[^_]\+\)\{3\}\).*/\1/'
```

or if you have `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^[^_]+_+((_*[^_]+){3}).*/\1/'
```

Testing:

```
echo "AAA_BBBB__CCC__GGGG___fffffffffffffff_hhhh" | sed -r 's/^[^_]+_+((_*[^_]+){3}).*/\1/'
```

Results:

```
BBBB__CCC__GGGG
```

---

---

For fun, let's say you'd like to find the substring between any number of groups starting from the beginning of the line for any length. For example, if you're trying for an offset of 4, for a length of 1, try:

```
sed -r 's/^([^_]+_+){4}((_*[^_]+){1}).*/\2/'
```

Results:

```
fffffffffffffff
```

Pretty cool huh?

Comment: @Markus: Don't forget to accept the answer if it has worked for you. Cheers.